# How do curly braces in R regex work?

Tags: regex, r, curly-braces

I am trying to understand how the curly braces in R regular expression work. The help files say:

{n}
The preceding item is matched exactly n times.

{n,}
The preceding item is matched n or more times.

{n,m}
The preceding item is matched at least n times, but not more than m times.

I have a vector like this:

```
b <- c("aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa")
```

When I do

```
b[grep("a{2}", b)]
```

I would expect it to return only "aa" but instead I get everything. In other words, it yields exactly the same result as

```
b[grep("a{2,}", b)]
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in this `aaa` input `a{2}` matches the first two `a`'s likewise for all the other elements. So the grep returns index  of all the elements. To do an exact string match, you must need to add anchors.

```
> b <- c("aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa")
> b[grep("^a{2}$", b)]
[1] "aa"
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end. So the above grep  returns  only the index of the element which has exactly two `a`'s ie, `1`.

**OR**

```
> b <- c("aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa")
> b[grep("\\ba{2}\\b", b)]
[1] "aa"
```

Adding `\b` word boundary will also works for this case.